# Find the average value from a result of the aggregation of a bucket in elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

This is what my data looks like

```
          "age" : "5-6",
          "gender" : "male",
          "id" : 3 , 
          "userType" : "dormant",
          "location" : "560101",
          "status" : "completed",
          "subject" : "hindi",
          "score" : 100,
          "date" : "2021-06-01"
}
```

I have multiple entries of such data for different user Ids , I want to calculate the average score Per user for a particular day ,week ,year.

This is what i have written till now :

```
POST /worksheetdata/_search
{

"aggs": {
  "hourlydata": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "field": "date",
      "calendar_interval":"year"
      , "extended_bounds": {
        "min": "2020",
        "max": "2021"
      }
      
    }
    ,
    "aggs": {
      "userId": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "id"
        }
        ,
        "aggs": {
          "avgScore": {
            "avg": {
              "field": "score"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
}
```

I am able to obtain average score per user in a bucket for a particular year ,

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "yearlydata" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1577836800000,
          "doc_count" : 0,
          "userId" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1609459200000,
          "doc_count" : 28,
          "userId" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 2,
                "doc_count" : 14,
                "avgScore" : {
                  "value" : 43.714285714285715
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : 1,
                "doc_count" : 8,
                "avgScore" : {
                  "value" : 54.0
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : 3,
                "doc_count" : 6,
                "avgScore" : {
                  "value" : 100.0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now how can i find the average of this userId.bucket and add it to the userId Object.

Comment: I dont know how to close this question but I found the solution after I realised i can try a few things after posting this , I am adding this comment so it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

```
 POST /worksheetdata/_search
{

"aggs": {
  "yearlydata": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "field": "date",
      "calendar_interval":"year"
      , "extended_bounds": {
        "min": "2020",
        "max": "2021"
      }
      
    }
    ,
    "aggs": {
      "userId": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "id"
        }
        ,
        "aggs": {
          "avgScore": {
            "avg": {
              "field": "score"
            }
          }
        }
      
        
      
      },
       "avgScore" :{
         "avg_bucket": {
           "buckets_path": "userId>avgScore"
         }
       }
    }
  }
  
}
}
```